# Same priming sugar when using larger bottles?

Tags: bottle-conditioning, priming-sugar

Been brewing & bottling for almost 5 years and never stumbled upon this.  This year's Christmas beer is going in 22 oz bottles. Do I use the same amount of priming sugar for the batch?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use the same amount of priming sugar, in the batch, and I use a mix of bottles. 12oz and 32oz. and they carbonate the same.

if you are adding sugar to individual bottles, then the amount would be different.

so the answer is Yes, for priming the batch, 
No if you add to each bottle.

Comment: Priming the batch. Question updated